# Save Parent Category Text and URL into Variables using Vanilla JavaScript

Tags: javascript

I want to save the parent category text and URL into variables. In the example below, it is Batting Gloves.

Here is the HTML.

```
<section class="breadcrumbs">
<ul>
  <li>
     <a href="/store" title="" class="crumb" style="display: none;">Home</a> 
  </li>
  <li>
     <a href="/store/browse/sports/_/N-84a" class="crumb ">Sports</a>
  </li>
  <li>
     <a href="/store/browse/sports/baseballsoftball/_/N-apf" class="crumb ">Baseball/Softball</a>
  </li>
  <li>
     <a href="/store/browse/sports/baseballsoftball/_/N-apm" class="crumb ">Batting Gloves</a>
  </li>
  <li class="crumb"><font color="#6e6e6e">  Nike Hyperdiamond Edge Girls' Batting Gloves</font></li>
</ul>
</section>
```

In the example above the variables would be:

```
pc = 'batting gloves'
pcURL = '/store/browse/sports/baseballsoftball/_/N-apm'
```

Javascript:

I don't have any idea of how to write this.

Comment: can you please provide more details of exactly what you want and what you've achieved so far

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can check my solution. Hope this will help.

I've used 
`.getAttribute('href');` and `.innerHTML` to get those values

```js
const crumbItems = document.querySelectorAll('li a.crumb');
const battingGlovesItem = crumbItems[crumbItems.length - 1];

const pc = battingGlovesItem.innerHTML;
const pcURL = battingGlovesItem.getAttribute('href');

console.log(`pc: ${pc},\npcURL: ${pcURL}`)
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
  <meta charset="utf-8">
  <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width">
  <title>JS Bin</title>
</head>
<body>
<section class="breadcrumbs">
<ul>
  <li>
     <a href="/store" title="" class="crumb" style="display: none;">Home</a> 
  </li>
  <li>
     <a href="/store/browse/sports/_/N-84a" class="crumb ">Sports</a>
  </li>
  <li>
     <a href="/store/browse/sports/baseballsoftball/_/N-apf" class="crumb ">Baseball/Softball</a>
  </li>
  <li>
     <a href="/store/browse/sports/baseballsoftball/_/N-apm" class="crumb ">Batting Gloves</a>
  </li>
  <li class="crumb"><font color="#6e6e6e">  Nike Hyperdiamond Edge Girls' Batting Gloves</font></li>
</ul>
</section>
</body>
</html>
```

Answer (score 0):

You can do it like this

```js
var target = document.querySelector("li:nth-child(4) a");
console.log("pc: " + target.textContent + "\npcURL: " + target.href);
```

```html
<section class="breadcrumbs">
  <ul>
    <li>
       <a href="/store" title="" class="crumb" style="display: none;">Home</a> 
    </li>
    <li>
       <a href="/store/browse/sports/_/N-84a" class="crumb ">Sports</a>
    </li>
    <li>
       <a href="/store/browse/sports/baseballsoftball/_/N-apf" class="crumb ">Baseball/Softball</a>
    </li>
    <li>
       <a href="/store/browse/sports/baseballsoftball/_/N-apm" class="crumb ">Batting Gloves</a>
    </li>
    <li class="crumb"><font color="#6e6e6e">  Nike Hyperdiamond Edge Girls' Batting Gloves</font></li>
  </ul>
</section>
```